# Pyenv not showing as a command

Tags: python, bash, debian, pyenv

When I write `pyenv` It says

```
Command 'pyenv' not found, did you mean:
command 'p7env' from deb libnss3-tools
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

I know this is very common and it is something with the path.  I have tried everything in all different files such as bashrc, bash_profile, zshrc etc. What I currently have is in my "bashrc" file:

```
export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

When I write `bash` and then reload the terminal it works, but I cannot change the python version.

I am using a Linux Debian distribution and pyenv version 1.2.27

Comment: what is the result of `echo $PATH` in the terminal you want to run `pyenv` in?

Comment: This is the result: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  You should take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].  Your question is not strictly code related so somewhat out of scope for SO, although a large community of linux users are here.  I would do: `which pyenv`, which should return nothing for you.  Then `sudo find / -name pyenv -print`.  This will show you where the `pyenv` executable is located on your machine.  Then add that directory to your PATH variable, in your `.bashrc`.  Do not forget the dot in front of bashrc.  Now it is possible it is not installed at all (like on mine), and that would require you to install it.

Comment: I understand this isn't helpful to the OP specifically but everyone here should know that `pyenv` has been updating the init system as of late. See [this PR](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/pull/1920) for details.

Comment: "but I cannot change the python version." Change it how? Please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

[Bash sources `~/.bashrc` only for interactive *non-login* shells](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files). So, in an interactive login shell, before you type `bash` to open an interactive non-login shell, your `~/.bashrc` file will not have been sourced yet. You can fix this by adding the following to your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```bash
if [[ -r ~/.bashrc ]]; then 
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, it worked like that (in the end of .bashrc):

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```